# ORDER BY with GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, sql, sqlite

There are two areas S1 and S2. Every area was visited two times to collect bumblebees. I want all species that has been found on each area as a comma separated string in alphabetical order.

```
area|    date  |species
--------------------------------
S1  |2021-04-01|B.terrestris
S1  |2021-04-01|B.cryptarum
S1  |2021-04-01|B.lapidarius
S1  |2021-06-01|B.terrestris
S1  |2021-06-01|B.lapidarius
S1  |2021-06-01|B.terrestris
S1  |2021-06-01|B.cryptarum
S1  |2021-06-01|B.lapidarius
S2  |2021-04-01|B.lapidarius
S2  |2021-06-01|B.lapidarius
S2  |2021-06-01|B.cryptarum
S2  |2021-06-01|B.cryptarum


S1|B.cryptarum,B.lapidarius,B.terrestris
S2|B.cryptarum,B.lapidarus
```

Why does a query like

```sql
SELECT 
  area, group_concat(DISTINCT species ORDER BY species ASC)
FROM table
GROUP BY area
```

not work in QGIS3? I receive a Syntax Error. When I remove `ORDER BY` I get the expected result except the alphabetical order. Why is that?

Comment: `SELECT` from the table with `ORDER BY area, species` in a sub-query, then `GROUP_CONCAT` in the outer. A consuming statement will keep that order if nothing changes it in betwen - you may need to `DISTINCT area, species` (or `GROUP BY area, species`) in the sub-query.

Comment: You cannot use `ORDER BY` within a subquery.

Comment: You can. The arbitrariness of order is a design choice, and until now SQLite follows the order of presentment, meaning that a consuming statement will keep the order of the providing statement. PostgreSQL and other DBS don't necessarily follow that design, but they, unlike SQLite, usually support inline `ORDER BY`. If still in doubt, [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering) has both this method, and an explicitly deterministic alternative with a good explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always thought that you cannot use `ORDER BY` in subqueries.
This query solves my issue:

```
SELECT 
  area, group_concat(DISTINCT species)
FROM (
  SELECT 
     area, species
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY species ASC
  )
GROUP BY area
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternation using processing tools and expressions (I know it's OT, but it might be useful)

[Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate) algorithm, set as below:

[image]

1. your layer
2. field to group
3. expression to use

expression used:

```
concatenate_unique( 
     group_by:="area",
     concatenator:=',',
     expression:="species",
     order_by:="species")
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I like your approch and it seems a simple way to change the concatenator if one prefers not to use a comma. But in my case a pure SQL solution is what I want.